# декораторы python list object is not callable

Tags: python

при наличии декоратора я получаю ошибку  - list object is not callable , без него соответственно все работает. Почему при декорировании я получаю ошибку?

```
from datetime import datetime


def timeit(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = datetime.now()
        result = func(*args)
        print(datetime.now() - start)
        return result

    return wrapper()


@timeit
def abc():
    some_list = [i for i in range(100) if i % 2 == 0]
    return some_list


print(abc())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Декоратор должен возвращать объект функции, а не её результат:

```py
def timeit(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = datetime.now()
        result = func(*args)
        print(datetime.now() - start)
        return result

    # return wrapper()
    return wrapper
```